# PHP return second value of 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, 2d

I have the following PHP code:

```
$special_files = array(
        array("Turnip", "Tweed"),
        array("Donald", "Trump")
    );
```

I want to be able to get the second value in a nested array by identifying a first. eg: **if_exists("Donald")** would return **"trump"**.

I've tried to recurse through the array but I'm at a loss on how to select the second value once the first is identified.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$special_files = array(
        array("Turnip", "Tweed"),
        array("Donald", "Trump")
    );

$search_val = "Donald";
$key = array_search($search_val, array_column($special_files,0));

$output = $special_files[$key][1];  //outputs "Trump"
```

[Here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$special_files%20=%20array(%5Cn%20array(%22Turnip%22,%20%22Tweed%22),%5Cn%20array(%22Donald%22,%20%22Trump%22)%5Cn%20);%5Cn%5Cn$search_val%20=%20%22Turnip%22;%5Cn$key%20=%20array_search($search_val,%20array_column($special_files,0));%5Cn%5Cnvar_dump($special_files[$key][1]);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn) is a working sample.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try the following:

```
foreach ($special_files as $special_file) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($special_file as $element) {
        if ($i==2) {
            echo ("Second value is: " . $element);
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `[1]` elements and index them by the `[0]` elements:

```
$lookup = array_column($special_files, 1, 0);
$result = isset($lookup['Donald']) ?: false;
```

The `$lookup` array yields:

```
Array
(
    [Turnip] => Tweed
    [Donald] => Trump
)
```